# Minumum of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is minimum of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{2a}{\sqrt{xy}}$ where $a\in
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ and $x>0$, $y>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1, $a>0$:
There is no minimum for this function. But an infimum of $f(x^*, y^*)=0$ exists at infinity.

Case 2, $a<0$:
There is no minimum again. The infimum is $f(x^*, y^*)=-\infty$ and $x^*=0,y^*=0$.

Case 3: $a=0$: The minimum exists in this trivial case as the function is zero throughout.

Comment: That was really simple.